# Entanglement Entropy

Tags: specific-reference, entropy, quantum-entanglement

I needed some references which involves, the basic definition and motivation for Entanglement Entropy, and its one or two applications to many-body physics/black holes.

Comment: What do you mean by QM1 and QM2?

Comment: I mean that which is based on the basic quantum mechanics and advanced quantum mechanics, and doesn't involve much of many body theory and quantum field theory

Comment: But condensed matter is all about many body problems...?

Comment: I am preparing for a presentation on "Entanglement Entropy from Condensed Matter Physics to Black Holes" hence I was looking for useful resources.

Comment: @genneth : I meant that it introduces stuff without asking much prerequisites of many body physics. Is it not possible to learn the subject without the knowledge of many body physics ?

Comment: The idea of using entanglement entropy in condensed matter arose as it became apparent that we needed tools to directly understand the many-body phenomenon not approachable by the usual methods of reducing it to a single-particle problem (even things like BCS are essentially single-particle; much of our current understanding is about justifying the places for which this is reasonable). So yes; to truly understand its use in condensed matter, you *need* to have a very good appreciation already of the truly complex problems it's trying to solve.

Comment: By the way, if you are a student, just keep following your taught courses --- entanglement entropy in condensed matter is an active area of research, so there simply are not easy to read papers for outsiders of the field yet --- partly because no one wants to take the time to write one, and partly because no one is sure what such a paper might look like.

Comment: Hi Jaswin - it's better to ask about what you want to know directly, rather than asking for a reference. People will still point you to relevant books and papers as needed. Could you edit your question along those lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard reference for quantum information is Nielsen and Chuang, Quantum Computation and Quantum Information. Here is the [Google books preview](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=-s4DEy7o-a0C&printsec=frontcover&dq=nielsen+and+chuang&hl=en&sa=X&ei=DC-JULbhBO7J0AWLuYDgBQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=entanglement%20of%20formation&f=false).

On the free side, I strongly recomment the "Quantum Entanglement" review by Horodecki brothers (they are quite famous in quantum information). It contains almost anything you'd want to know about entanglement and references to the rest. You can download it freely from arXiv: http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0702225

None of these require you to learn either many body theory or quantum field theory. But for many body theory and QFT, this is usually a good choice [Quantum Field Theory of Many Body Systems](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/019922725X). I'm afraid when it comes to quantum many body theory, basic QFT is a must and you will not be able to do without it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the subject, but I found interesting resources below, I hope it will help you :

[Entanglement Entropy in QFT,  Holographic Entanglement Entropy](http://www2.yukawa.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~takayana/CERNEE.pdf)

[Entanglement entropy from a holographic viewpoint](http://arxiv.org/abs/1204.2450)

[Entanglement Entropy in Many-Body Systems](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0703044)

[Area laws for the entanglement entropy](http://arxiv.org/abs/0808.3773)